# Finding an expression for $\sin^{2n}$ as sums of sines

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, recreational-mathematics

Here’s a problem I started working on today:Express $\sin^{2n}(\theta)$ as a sum of sines whose angles are multiples of $\theta$.

As a hint we have $e^{in\theta}-e^{-in\theta}=2i\sin(n\theta)$

I can’t seem to figure out how to show this. If it were cosine, this would have been a different story – just pairing terms. But I can’t even figure out how to express $\sin^2(\theta)$ as a sum of sines. Any hints?

Comment: Yeah, I want to use it. It might help me understand the problem better

Comment: I assume the question meant in terms of $\cos{(n\theta)}$ as for example$$\sin^2{(\theta)}=\frac12-\frac12\cos{(2\theta)}$$

Comment: No, that’s the puzzling part. If it allowed $\cos$ and $\sin$ I can solve it. It only says $\sin$. There are situations where you’d want to use $sin$ for instance when $n=2$ @PeterForeman

Comment: You can't express an even function as a linear combination of odd functions.

Comment: @RobertIsrael You’re right! That’s a great point. I suspected the question might be wrong but I didn’t know how to justify it. Thank you!